# EmbedBuilder discord bot помогите решить проблему с иконой

Tags: c#

Вообщем мне нужно слева от уровня поставить иконку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
, я пользуюсь методом  .AddField("Уровень" , "0/10", false), он не принимает иконки, как можно решить данную проблему, ибо не нашёл в документации метода решающего мою проблему, библиотека discord.net раздел EmbedBuilder.

P.S Я делал по примеру из другого бота и да иконка там реально стоит слева от уровня.

Comment: Там наверно не иконка, а смайлик? Ибо на сколько мне известно, картинки вставляются там только в пару мест, не более.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Нет, там именно иконка я не могу в этом чате пруф приложить

Comment: Возьмите любой генератор, например [этот](https://eb.nadeko.bot/) и попробуйте там добавить вашу иконку. Можете взять [этот сайт](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) и посмотреть как это будет выглядеть в самом дискорде. Я лично возможностей добавить иконку - не вижу.